# Enable ejabberd web interface in mongooseIM

Tags: mongoose-im

When I do bin/mongooseim start and the mongooseim is running, then I put on url `127.0.0.1:5280/` I have as result on web a white page, I think that this is mean that `ejabberd_cowboy` ( having the port 5280) is listenning but I haven't the interface khnown of ejabberd.

In ejabberd.cfg I have  these lines for Cowboy

```
{listen,
[
%% HTTP endpoints
{ {{cowboy_port}}, ejabberd_cowboy, [
{num_acceptors, 10},
{max_connections, 1024},
{modules, [
Modules used here should also be listed in the MODULES section.
{"localhost", "/api", mongoose_api,
[{handlers,[mongoose_api_metrics,mongoose_api_users]}]},    
{"_", "/http-bind", mod_bosh},
{"_", "/ws-xmpp", mod_websockets}
%% Uncomment to serve static files
%{"_", "/static/[...]", cowboy_static,
%  {dir, "/var/www", [{mimetypes, cow_mimetypes, all}]}
%},
]}]},
```

Comment: Thank y to answer me.

Comment: This snippet comes from `ejabberd.cfg` template you can find in the repo, not from the generated config which should be found in the release. Are you sure you're using this file? I know this by `{{cowboy_port}}` instead of the port number itself.

Comment: yes yes , i make first make rel , then under this rel/mongooseim i do bin/mongooseim and i have under rel/mongooseim/etc the file ejabberdcfg generated but i don't understand why i have only white page when i put on url 127.0.0.1:5280

Comment: You have reason the code that i print is in the template not from the ejabberd.cfg

Comment: My problem is resolved : MongooseIM hasn't interface on web